# Jquery clone children

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery clone and children concepts for my project. I'm using one table within div (class is clonedInput), by clicking one button I'm cloning the whole div and inserting it after the div. In this time:
"

```
var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
 $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
```

"
by using this I'm increasing the div id. At the same time I want to increase the table tr and td's id. For that I tried `children.attr()`. But this is not increasing the table ids. Can anyone clarify this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you're trying to do? It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Page's layout is needed.

Comment: I'm trying form adding Details. Once user is adding data, for example bus route details, if they want to add more routes, by clicking the add route button we are repeating the table details.

Comment: we need more info - show the page layout and js where you try increase table id attr.

Comment: You will have to show your HTML and clarify your question.

Comment: Try using elem.find('td') instead of elem.children() because children selects only the immediate descendants.

Comment: can you setup jfiddle so its easy to resolve

Answer (score 2):

I have a function which creates inputs in a row with incremented ids. This is not  the thing you are looking for but i am sure it will give you a fairly good idea to how to do the task.

```
var numbers =0
$(function() {
var newRowNum = 0;

    $('#addnew').click(function() {
        newRowNum++;
        /////////////  <a>    <td>    <tr>
        var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();
        ///////////// In the line below <tr> is created
        var newRow = addRow.clone();
        $('input', addRow).val('');
        $('td:first-child', newRow).html();
        $('td:last-child', newRow).html('<a href="" class="remove">Remove<\/a>');
        $('input', newRow).each(function(i) {
            var newID = newRowNum + '_' + i;
            $(this).attr('id', newID).attr('name', newID);
        });
        addRow.before(newRow);

        $('a.remove', newRow).click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });
    numbers = newRowNum;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what are you trying to do, but my guess is that you can try:

```
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);
    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone();

    newElem.attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
```

the whole

```
$('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
```

part may not be giving you clone object but rather boolean result or some integer.

If the problem is not resolved you may try append() function also.

Comment: @Dinesh.B Glad to be help. Don't forget to right check correct answer if that's the case.